# Date & float conversion on SQL Server condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help understanding a bit of SQL.

```
SELECT   * 
FROM [MyTable]  
WHERE CAST((GETDATE()-[MyDate]) as float) >= cast(0 as float) /24/60 
  AND CAST((GETDATE()-[MyDate]) as float) <  cast(499999 as float) /24/60
```

1. I pretty much understand that its a date search, what I don't get is the float conversion. Why would you use that? **Is that better for performance?**
2. I understand that the first condition is: date higher or the same as 1900/01/01, what I just don't understand is **what date is: 499999/24/60** and **why is there the magic division**?

Thanks for help and explanation.

Comment: 24 hours in a day, 60 minutes in an hour. So for some reason he wants to make sure the difference between the 2 dates is less then 499999 minutes.

Comment: The code is unnecessarily obtuse and bad for performance. I don't know the intent but it will return rows with a date between 347.221527777778 days ago and now. It should be refactored like `MyDate > DATEADD(day, -347, GETDATE()) AND MyDate <= GETDATE()` so that an index on `MyDate` can be used efficiently. Tweak this criteria according to your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting dates to floats is an old style way of dealing with dates.  I think it might go back to more limited date functionality in SQL Server 2000.  But it might also be a legacy of folks familiar with dates in Excel (where they are floats).

There is no performance advantage.  In fact, such type conversions prevent the use of indexes.

For your two items of code, I think you want:

```
WHERE MyDate >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND
      MyDate < DATEADD(DAY, 499999, '1899-12-30')
```

The last is arbitrary.  A constant value such as:

```
WHERE MyDate >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND
      MyDate < '3000-01-01'
```

makes more sense.  You could use the actual date represented -- `'3268-12-11'` -- but that would probably confuse anyone reading the code.

EDIT:

On re-reading the question, the logic makes even LESS sense than it originally did.  It seems to be something like:

```
WHERE MyDate < CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND
      MyDate >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -499999, GETDATE())
```

And that causes an overflow.

Comment: Shouldn the first condition be MyDate <= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), meaning MyDate is not int the future?

Comment: @DavidWaldo . . . I think you are right based on the question.  However, that interpretation results in a date/time overflow, so I sort of assumed that the logic was inverted in the question.

Comment: It's minutes not days.